# Rollback git pull request on cpanel

Tags: laravel, git

I just did a pull request and now the entire page won't load and I only get a HTTP ERROR 500 without any other explanation I have no clue what is going on, the page initially loaded fine but then it just refused to load again. How can I go back to the previous version that was on the server?

I did a regular `git pull origin master` and I even did a `git fetch --all` to see if maybe something happened with the first pull but it stays the same.

How can I go back? or any suggestions on how to see what the error actually is? I'm using Laravel.

Comment: Download your entire project as back up, then run `git revert`

Comment: @STA Will that affect the data in the database?

Comment: Not affect at database, but take backup everything